# Image - detect low contrast edge

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection

I have a picture with high and low contrast transitions.

[image]

I need to detect edges on the above picture. I need binary image. I can easily detect the black and "dark" blue edges with Sobel operator and thresholding.

However, the edge between "light" blue and "light" yellow color is problematic.

I start with smooth image with median filter for each channel to remove noise.

What I have tried already to detect edges:

- Sobel operator
- Canny operator
- Laplace
- grayscale, RGB, HSV, LUV color spaces (with multichannel spaces, edges are detected in each channel and then combined together to create one final edge image)
- Preprocessing RGB image with gamma correction (the problem with preprocessing is the image compression. The source image is JPG and if I use preprocessing edge detection often ends with visible grid caused by JPG macroblocks.)

So far, Sobel on RGB works best but the low-contrast line is also low-contrast.

[image]

Further thresholding remove this part. I consider edge everything that is under some gray value. If I use high threshold vales like 250, the result for low contrast edge is better but the remaining edges are destroyed. Also I dont like gaps in low-contrast edge.

[image]

So, if I change the threshold further and say that all except white is edge, I have edges all over the place.

[image]

Do you have any other idea how to combine low and high contrast edge detection so that the edges are without gaps as much as possible and also not all over the place?

*Note: For test I use mostly OpenCV and what is not available in OpenCV, I programm myself*

Comment: Do you have any other knowledge about the line you seek? E.g. is it always parallel to the other edges? Always a similar distance? Are the colours either side always yellow-ish and blue-ish?

Comment: Yes, the line is mostly parallel to the other edges and distance can be considered similar within a single image. Outter color is always yellow-ish (it is background), but the other colors can be different.

Comment: I have tried to use yellow-ish color info within the HSV, but in H channel both colors are indistinguishable. S is better but still very similar to only V (which is very similar to grayscale of the input image only).

Comment: This is a compressed image, is there a better original ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sadly no, the original data are lost because data were saved as JPG with 70% quality (this is quite a problem since some operations result in visible JPG macroblocks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO this is barely doable, if doable at all if you want an automated solution.

Here I used binarization in RGB space, by assigning every pixel to the closest color among two colors representative of the blue and yellow. (I picked isolated pixels, but picking an average over a region would be better.)

[image]

Maybe a k-means classifier could achieve that ?

---

**Update:**

Here is what a k-means classifier can give, with 5 classes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have used quantization from pngQuant library ([link](https://pngquant.org/)) and divide the image to tiles - each tile has different quantization and as a result, the border is clearly visible.

Answer (score 1):

All kudos and points to Yves please for coming up with a possible solution. I was having some fun playing around experimenting with this and felt like sharing some actual code, as much for my own future reference as anything. I just used **ImageMagick** in Terminal, but you can do the same thing in Python with [Wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand/).

So, to get a K-means clustering segmentation with 5 colours, you can do:

```
magick edge.png -kmeans 5 result.png
```

[image]

If you want a swatch of the detected colours underneath, you can do:

```
magick edge.png \( +clone -kmeans 5 -unique-colors -scale "%[width]x20\!" \) -background none -smush +10 result.png
```

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, ImageMagick, wand, image processing, segmentation, k-means, clustering, swatch.